# I want to get count of installations for my app from app store and google play (programmatically), is there an official api

Tags: java

I am developing flutter mobile application with java(springboot) backend, I want to get the number of downloads(installations) for my app using java(springboot) from google play and play store.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is the google play api that supports aggregated reports. I think it can help you.
[https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870?p=financial_export&rd=1#export&zippy=%2Cdetailed-reports%2Caggregated-reports)

Comment: And there is the app store api what you want
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/download_sales_and_trends_reports